# How to use two components in html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp

I want to use two components in one html.

For instance

index.html:

```
</div>

<div id='rightComp'>
</div>
```

app.jsx:

```
window.onload=function(){
    React.render(
       <leftcomp/>, document.getElementById('leftComp')
       <rightComp/>, document.getElementById('rightComp')
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `React.render` twice, once with each React element/DOM node pair.

```
window.onload=function(){
    React.render(<leftcomp/>, document.getElementById('leftComp'))
    React.render(<rightComp/>, document.getElementById('rightComp'))
}
```

With that said, it's considered better practice to have one component that contains both `leftcomp` and `rightcomp`, and to just render that wrapper component into a single DOM node.